# Conversion from String to long array and back doesn't work

Tags: java, string, encoding, base64, long-integer

I am sorry for the confusing title, but I couldn't figure out how to describe my problem with a better one.

I am writing a program that converts a string to a long vector that should be reversible (to read the information back). The conversion to the long array appears to be fine to me. I use base 64 as a middle step in order to make the number of bytes in a nicer way, to handle for the other processing parts that I have to do.

```
    public long[] str2long(String s)
    {
        final byte[] authBytes = s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        final String encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(authBytes);
        long[] array = new long[encoded.length()];
        int i=0;
        for(char c: encoded.toCharArray()){
            array[i] = (long) c;
//             System.out.print(array[i] + " ");
             i++;
        }
        return array;
    }
```

The problem is that even tough the following code appears to be the exact inverse of the code above, in reality it is not, and the base 64 back conversion gives this error: `Illegal base64 character 5b`.

```
public String long2str(long[] array)
{
    char[] chArray = new char[array.length];
    int i=0;
    for(long c: array){
        chArray[i] = (char) c;
        i++;
    }
    String s = Arrays.toString(chArray);
    final byte[] decoded= Base64.getDecoder().decode(s);
    try {
        s = new String(decoded, "UTF-8");
        return s;
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Encryption.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return null;
}
```

So, my questions are:

What's different in the second method that I am missing? I think it might be the `StandardCharsets.UTF_8`, but I am not sure.

How can I make this function `long2str(long[] array)` work like 
`long2str(str2long(String s)) == String s` ?

If you want, I can post the test cases that I am using to try to verify this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `long2str` method, change:

```
String s = Arrays.toString(chArray);
```

to:

```
String s = new String(chArray);
```

When you use `Arrays.toString()` you are getting a `String` of the form `[Y, W, J, j, Z, G, V, m, Z, 2, h, ...]`, which is not a valid base 64 String. To get the `String` that contains all the characters of `chArray`, you should use the appropriate `String` constructor.